# Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ee:object-store-caching-strategy'

Tags: maven, caching, mule

I have added `ee:object-store-caching-strategy` to my mule project using maven.

It runs perfect in anypoint studio using mule server 3.7.2 EE, but when deploying to mule standalone 3.7.0 CE I get this error:

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ee:object-store-caching-strategy'

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an Enterprise Edition feature (hence the `ee` schema name), that's why it's not working when deployed to a Community Edition runtime.